# Bigquery SQL function to check entire table for null values

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

First i need a Bigquery sql function to check entire tables within my dataset for any null values.

Second based on the results (null values found or not), I need to execute the downstream dependent tables using Airflow scheduler.

This is condition: If any null values found in the table, subsequent downstream table which is depending on the table which has null values should stop executing through the Airflow Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we have any functions as such in Bigquery to scan entire tables in dataset..

But for 2.) We can set the trigger rule and setup task dependency accordingly in the airflow to skip the downstream tasks whenever null's are found. And you can stop the dag you can also keep email alert without even failing the task even if null's found.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/concepts.html?highlight=trigger#trigger-rules